# нужно создать функцию которая протестирует: можем ли мы создать объект на основе класса Form, при этом передав в него 2 параметра

Tags: php, phpunit

вот мой класс Form:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

class Form {
    private $login;
    private $pass;

    public function __construct($login, $pass) {
        $this->login = $login;
        $this->pass = $pass;
    }
}
```

а это FormTest

```
<?php
use App\Models\Form;

class FormTest extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {
    private $obj;

    public function setUp(): void {
        $this->obj = new Form('login', 'pass');
    }

    public function tearDown(): void {
        $this->obj = NULL;
    }

    public function testCanWeCreateObjFormWithTwoArguments() {

    }
}
```

помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Что значит - можем создать? Почему может случиться что __не сможем__?

Comment: ну просто нужно создать такой тест

Comment: И что этот тест должен проверять? Не в абстрактных понятиях, а в конкретных - что а равно б, ц равно трем и так далее.

Comment: нужно создать функцию с тестированием, и в ней создать объект на основе класса Form, запустить и проверить создаётся ли объект корректно, вот только как это сделать я не понимаю, помогите пж

Comment: А я не понимаю __что именно__ вы не можете сделать. Объект вроде как есть. Документация по phpUnit тоже в наличии.

Comment: Но как это протестировать, я не могу понять

Comment: Что именно протестировать?

Comment: Протестировать корректно создаётся объект или нет, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Что для вас - __объект создается корректно__? И второе - вы документацию по phpunit открывали?

Comment: Корректно то есть без ошибок, вот когда мы создаём объект и передаём два параметра это корректно, а если к примеру 3 то не корректно, и я не могу понять как это организовать

Comment: Я слабо представляю кто может передать в конструктор три аргумента вместо двух и зачем. И в целом php не строг к количеству аргументов, которое превышает число объявленных в функции. То есть я в ваш конструктор могу 1000 аргументов передать и ничего. Но если уж надо - то проверьте в конструкторе что число аргументов равно 2 и если нет - бросайте Exception например.

Comment: Ну, у меня просто такое задание, которое мне нужно выполнить, а я не могу понять как(конечно в реальности никто такие тесты писать не будет), но мне нужно написать тест, вы можете помочь или нет?